# Centralizar divs - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bem, dividi a parte de conteúdo, em duas divs, col-md-6, só que elas não ficam centralizadas em relação ao site, apesar de estarem no centro, estão colocadas no lado esquerdo, deixando o lado direito um pouco vazio.
Segue o código das divs.

```
        <div class="content">

            <div class="container clearfix">
                                <div class="col-md-6 configdiv">
                                    <img src="/layout/images/imagem1.png" />
                                    <h5>TITULO 1</h5>
                                    <p>
                                    Oi, tudo bem? Oi, tudo bem? Oi, tudo bem?
                                    Oi, tudo bem?
                                    Oi, tudo bem?
                                    <p>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="/layout/images/iconemail.png" />
                                        <img src="/layout/images/iconefb.png" />
                                        <img src="/layout/images/iconett.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 configdiv">
                                    <img src="/layout/images/imagem2.png" />
                                    <h5>TITULO 2</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        Oi, tudo bem?
                                    <p>
                                    <div>
                                    <img src="/layout/images/iconemail.png" />
                                    <img src="/layout/images/iconefb.png" />
                                    <img src="/layout/images/iconett.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section><!-- #content end -->
```

E o CSS tem isso:

```
    .configdiv {border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
           margin-right: 28px;
           margin-bottom: 25px;
           padding: 10px;
```

Lembrando, essas duas divs col-md-6, ficam uma do lado da outra, quero que fique centralizada em relação a tela!
Conteúdo do content:

```
        Content----------------------------------------------------*/
        #content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #FFF;
    }

     #content p { line-height: 1.8; }

    .content-wrap {
    position: relative;
    padding: 80px 0;
    }

    #content .container { position: relative; }


       /* ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Você adicionou um `margin-right` na div que contem o col-md-6 isso pode estar causando o espaçamento, outra coisa, a classe `content` possui algum css ?

Comment: Já tinha feito o teste, sem o margin-right, as duas divs ficariam colocadas, aí adicionei o margin right pra div que está do lado esquerdo da tela, ficar meio separada da do lado direito.

Comment: Tentei colocar em outra classe o margin right, deixando só nas div que está do lado esquerdo, mesmo assim, não fica do jeito que quero! E no content tem isso:

Comment: Adicionei o content no post.

Comment: Use tags relevantes "a duvida" por favor, cada tag tem uma descrição para o entendimento. Nota: bootstrap é uma tag para um procedimento (ou série de procedimentos)  quando um aplicativo é iniciado ou é feito uma requisição web. Para bootstrap "framework front-end" use twitter-bootstrap. Boa sorte com as respostas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="configdiv">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="configdiv">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Dessa forma as divs ficaram espaçadas e centralizadas uma ao lado da outra.

**Container:** Centralizara as divs.

**Col-md-6:** Os cols criam um `padding` de `15px` para cada lado se você adicionar um `border` junto a `div` do `col` elas vao ficar coladas ja se você adicionar em uma `div` dentro do `col` irá funcionar da forma que você quer, não adicionei a classe `ROW` pois ela remove o `padding` adicionado pelo `col` as divs.

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo não mexer margin laterias da classe de coluna (col-md-*) pois atrapalha a estrutura grid.

Você pode centralizar os textos usando a classe `.text-center` ou `col-md-offset-*` para empurrar o bloco no lado esquerdo, por exemplo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou diminuir mais o bloco (centralizar mais):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou assim, um pouco gambiarra:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="centraliza">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.centraliza {
    width: 555px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 375px; //Se quer altura automática, é só deletar essa linha
}
```

Coloquei `div.centraliza` no lugar `div.container` pois possui quase mesmo comportamento porém o `.centraliza` você aproveita com qualquer tamanho.

Comment: As divs ficaram muito reduzidas. O Tamanho delas tem que ser W:555, H: 375, tem como mudar isso?

Comment: Isso é outra alternativa, é mais manual.
Você tem que usar o `div` com `margin:auto` e tamanhos fixos que centraliza.
Dá uma googlada com título `centralizar DIV HTML`, deixa o bootstrap pro lado pois o objetivo desse framework Bootstrap é estruturar e inserir elementos prontos.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, de uma olhada

Comment: Tem outro objeto em baixo, col-md-12, tem que ter um margin-bottom pra não ficar essas duas divs, com essa div de baixo. Se eu usar tamanhos fixos, como fica o responsivo?...

Comment: Usa a tecnica design responsive no CSS para alterar o valor da classe `.centraliza`

Answer (score 0):

Veja se esse código resolve seu problema. 
Repare que antes do col-md-6 temos uma div col-md-12 e se quiser centralizar o conteudo o text-align:center.

```css
.configdiv 
{
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  //margin-right: 28px;
  //margin-bottom: 28px;
  padding: 10px;
}

//caso queira uma div md-6 lado a lado na tela margin-right e margin-bottom devem estar comentados ou retirados do seu código. Caso queira distancia entre eles use col-md-offset-1 2 ou 3...
```

```html
<div class="content">
            <div class="col-md-12 container clearfix">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 configdiv" style="text-align:center">
                        <img src="/layout/images/imagem1.png" />
                        <h5>TITULO 1</h5>
                        <p>
                            Oi, tudo bem? Oi, tudo bem? Oi, tudo bem?
                            Oi, tudo bem?
                            Oi, tudo bem?
                        <p>
                        <div>
                            <img src="/layout/images/iconemail.png" />
                            <img src="/layout/images/iconefb.png" />
                            <img src="/layout/images/iconett.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 configdiv" style="text-align:center">

                        <img src="/layout/images/imagem2.png" />
                        <h5>TITULO 2</h5>
                        <p>
                            Oi, tudo bem?
                        <p>
                        <div class="center-block">
                            <img src="/layout/images/iconemail.png" />
                            <img src="/layout/images/iconefb.png" />
                            <img src="/layout/images/iconett.png" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
```