# Centralizar DIV

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css3

Como faço para centralizar essa div :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
.centralizar {
   width: 80%;
   background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Duplicata de alguma dessas? [Busca: centralizar CSS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=centralizar%20css) | [Centralizar divs - Bootstrap](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75047/70) | [Centralizar div no Bootstrap](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115891/70)

Comment: @Bacco segundo link, pois o terceiro é alinhamento vertical e horizontal. Mas se for questão de CSS acho que esta resposta é a melhor http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/807/3635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vai depender um pouco do tipo de centralização que você deseja. Vou colocar alguns exemplos aqui.

Centralização com `margin`

```css
.center1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Alinha Elementos no Centro</h2>
<p>Para centralizar um elemento verticalmente, use margin: auto;</p>

<div class="center1">
  <p><b>Observação: </b>O margin:auto não funciona no IE8 a menos que um !DOCTYPE esteja declarado.</p>
</div>
```

Centralização com `text-align`

```css
.center2 {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<h2>Centraliza Texto</h2>

<div class="center2">
  <p>Texto centralizado</p>
</div>
```

Alinhamento vertical com `padding`

```css
.center3 {
  padding: 70px 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<h2>Centralizando Verticalmente</h2>
<p>Usamos padding para centralizar a div vericalmente:</p>

<div class="center3">
  <p>Estou verticalmente centralizada.</p>
</div>
```

Alinhamento central com `padding` e `text-align`

```css
.center4 {
  padding: 70px 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  

<h2>Centralizando verticalmente e horizontalmente</h2>
<p>Usamos padding e text-align para centralizar vertical e horizontalmente:</p>

<div class="center4">
  <p>Estou vertical e horizontalmente centralizada.</p>
</div>
```

Centralização com `line-height`

```css
 
.center5 {
  line-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}
.center p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h2>Centralizando com Line Height</h2>
<p>Usamos line-height com um valor que é igual a propriedade height, para centralizar o elemento:</p>

<div class="center5">
  <p>Estou vertical e horizontalmente centralizada com line-height.</p>
</div>
```

Centralização com `position` e `transform`

```css
.center6 {
height: 200px;
position: relative;
border: 3px solid green;
}

.center p {
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Centralizando com position e transform</h2>
<p> Mostra como centralizar de forma horizontal e vertical usando positioning e transform:</p>

<div class="center6">
  <p>Estou alinhada vertical e horizontalmente.</p>
</div>

<p>Obs: O transform não é suportado no IE8 e versões anteriores a ele.</p>
```

Comment: Uma ótima resposta Diéfani, só que recomendo dar atenção as respostas já existentes em perguntas mais antigas para que o conteudo não fique espalhado, esse tipo de pergunta já foi feita várias vezes, eu marquei a pergunta como duplicata desta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/806/3635 mas não deu tempo de fecha-la, por isso peço-lhes que deem apoio as perguntas já respondidas marcando as duplicatas e evitando responde-las, obrigado ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pode seguir este exemplo :

```css
body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
  background: #006633;
}
.centralizar {
   width: 80%;
   background: #fff;
   margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="centralizar">Centro !</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Uma ótima resposta MagicHat, só que recomendo dar atenção as respostas já existentes em perguntas mais antigas para que o conteudo não fique espalhado, esse tipo de pergunta já foi feita várias vezes, eu marquei a pergunta como duplicata desta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/806/3635 mas não deu tempo de fecha-la, por isso peço-lhes que deem apoio as perguntas já respondidas marcando as duplicatas e evitando responde-las, obrigado ;)